# std::thread libstdc++-v3 where is this memory freed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gnu

I was reading libstdc++-v3 `std::thread` implementation and I saw that a unique_ptr is released after the thread is created, so when it runs out of scope, the memory that is potentially used by the new thread isn't deallocated. (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6b1633378b74bed1d999a0ae2549088515a30ba0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/thread.cc#L152). As far as I'm concerned, one must manually delete the manual pointer later, but I can't find where that is done. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, just found.
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6b1633378b74bed1d999a0ae2549088515a30ba0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/thread.cc#L81
It casts a `void*` to a `thread::_State*` to a `thread::_State_ptr`(which is the actual std::unique_ptr) to use RAII. This code style is a bit unreadable imo. I thought about deleting the question, but gonna leave it here in case anyone is interested